# calculating frequency of jitter/wave distortion in an image

Tags: image-processing, frequency, distortion, jitter

Is there a way to calculate the frequency of the jitter/wave distortion in the below image?
and how can I measure the distortion so I can correct it?
[image]

I tried to calculate the frequency on a part of the image (the horn) by creating a line plot profile where the x pixels are the intensity and y pixels the distance
[image]

here is the plot profile
[image]

and I am thinking of extracting the local minimas/maximas per certaing number of pixels, I don't know if this approach is correct, or is there a better way to calculate it

Comment: have you tried any approach? such as looking into the spectrum, magnitude, and angle of the `FFT` transform?

Comment: good luck with that picture. we humans can tell because we can apply assumptions about the picture content. a machine can't. how is the computer supposed to know that the animal's horns __are not__ supposed to look like that, but straight?

Comment: yes I tried to create a line profile plotting along the jitter margin, where y pixels are the distance value, and x pixels are the intricate value, and then identifying the local minima/maxima values per 150 pixel